# How to completely get rid of the ice in the biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft Java 1.18.2 in creative mode, already have something large built, but do not want the ice to continue developing in this biome. I was wondering if there is any way I can get rid of the ice completely in this part of the map/biome.

I have tried manually breaking down the ice, but it continues to grow back. I would also like to keep it so there are no farms visible to make it so the ice does not grow (but don't mind if it's hidden!).

No mods, please.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ice):

> Water source blocks in a snowy biome eventually freeze into ice if exposed to the sky from directly above, the light level immediately adjacent to the water block on all sides is less than 13, and there is at least one horizontally adjacent non-water (and non-waterlogged) block.

So you may need to keep all the surface well lit, or cover the water with something.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on the base's design, it sounds like you could surround the water with waterlogged blocks, like stairs or trapdoors